# Rescue URI::InvalidURIError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

Why my `rescue` didn't rescue from exception?

error

```
    2016-07-14T09:43:06.062Z 6490 TID-ox0hrishg WARN: URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): 
2016-07-14T09:43:06.062Z 6490 TID-ox0hrishg WARN: /Users/stas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:18:in `rescue in split'



  begin
   xml_loop(@xml.products)
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    index = @xml.get_index(XmlTracker.last.xml_id)
    xml_loop(@xml.products[index...900])
 else
 ....
end
```

How to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put `end` for the `begin` block

```
  begin
    xml_loop(@xml.products)
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    index = @xml.get_index(XmlTracker.last.xml_id)
    xml_loop(@xml.products[index...900])
  end
```